# rsyslog suppose to writing remote logs to a file by remote host name or ip address?

Tags: linux, rsyslog

I am using rsyslog on rhel 7.3. I have already defined the following configs in /etc/rsyslog.conf file

`$PreserveFQDN on
$template Remote10514,"/data/logs/%HOSTNAME%/%HOSTNAME%-%$YEAR%%$MONTH%%$DAY%.log"`

All the remote device/host name are resolvable.  I notice some device logs directory are created by IP and some are FQDN. I have also included one of the hostname in the /etc/host file to troubleshoot if thats the problem.

I saw someone reporting that it is sort of buggy but wanted to confirm if there is something wrong in my config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working after making the following change

`/%FROMHOST%/%FROMHOST%-`   from  `%HOSTNAME%/%HOSTNAME%`